# calculate the number of characters in a variable

Tags: windows, batch

I am trying to calculate the length of an output from a set. It is very important to me I try to calculate this with out enable delayaedexpansion
just raw batch.

```
@echo off
cls
set aaa=asdf
  for %%a in ("%aaa%") do (
  set /a bbb=%%~za + 0 
  echo %bbb%
)
```

If I do not add the +0, it keeps returning missing operand. If I put the +0 on , it keeps returning ECHO is off. This is not the first time I have tried to do a numerical echo. I am confused as to why letters will echo just fine but numbers will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `%%~z` only works for files, not for variables. So, write the contents of the variable to a file, and get the file size.

What about this:

```
@echo off
set aaa=asdf

:: Write variable to file
set tmpfile=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%
echo %aaa%> %tmpfile%

:: Determine filesize, subtract 2 bytes for newline
for /F "usebackq" %%a in ('%tmpfile%') do set /a size=%%~za - 2

del %tmpfile%

echo Size: %size%
```

Comment: I am new at this, I am not sure if this is the correct answer or just one of many. It works for what I need. Almost exactly what I was going for. I am trying to teach my self this from web site searches, I feel I am doing pretty well, I just do not get all the lingo. After 30 minutes of someone on here barking rudely and then deleting everything we discussed. I researched more and realized this is called stringlength, So Berend I am very appreciative you read what I wrote and did not just tell me, I see your script is broken, what are you going to do about it.